# What do we need to define a category?

Tags: category-theory

I used some results from the category theory without thinking about its foundations. However, after reading a few topics on MSE, this subject haunts me.

My question is:

> What do we need to define a category?

According to some books, a category consists of a *class* $\text{Obj}$ of objects and a *set* $\text{Hom}$ of morphisms which satisfy some axioms. For me it means, that to define a category we need some set theory. But there are many different set theories. Do they raise different category theories?

Also, as I understand, when we are talking about specific categories, like $\text{Set}$, $\text{Grp}$,... we mean models (interpretations) of the axioms of a category. Is it correct?

Comment: A category is [concrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category) when there is a faithful functor into $\mathrm{Set}$. Loosely speaking, it means that each object is a set, and $\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)$ is a set of maps from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: @user10676 oh, sorry.. by concrete categories I mean "specific categories" as $\text{Set}, \text{Grp}, \text{Vec},...$ where the class of objects is determined

Comment: There are several different (but more or less equivalent) ways of defining categories even within a single set theory.  You can also look at things like [ETCS](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS) if you want to avoid set theory.

Comment: Most categories which have a proper class of objects also have a proper class of morphisms, for example the category of sets.  However, it is common in situations like that for each Hom set to have a set of morphisms.

Comment: Around ETCS, in particular, I strongly recommend Leinster's *Rethinking Set Theory*: http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6543

Comment: @Berci It is a very cool, very approachable paper! The most convincing piece for non-logician people might actually be the "earthquake" section...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, one needs to adopt a [foundation of mathematics](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/foundation+of+mathematics) to define a set, category, and other mathematical objects!

Different foundations give different category theories. Some 'categories', which are called big in one foundation, do not exists in another, *e.g.* the functor category between two large categories and the localisation of a category with respect to a proper class (large set) of its morphisms. The meanings of the terms (*small*) *set* and (*proper*) *class*, and the operations you can perform on them, depend on the adopted foundation. Shulman's [Set theory for category theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1279) and Mac Lane's [One universe as a foundation for category theory](http://link.springer.com/10.1007/BFb0059147) discuss the effect of the foundation on the resulting category theory, although the latter is more focused on the advantages of a specific foundation.